# WCF Exception during writing an event into event log

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, events, exception

Exception during writing event log on host machine(Windows 2008 R2) hosting WCF Service named my machine
 from WCFClient (Windows 7) running within domain but on a different machine.

WCF Client is impersonated to access resources on Server.

So far following links have not helped

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028427#appliesto

http://forums.asp.net/t/1131903.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa379567 (Detals about SDDL)
http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/jorge/archive/2008/03/26/parsing-sddl-strings.aspx (SDDL)

similar question on SO without any answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456444/allow-wcf-services-writing-to-custom-event-log-under-windows-2008-r2-server

Exception is as follows

System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Cannot open log for source 'MyService'. You may not have write access. (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open log for source 'MyService'. You may not have write access. ----> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

--- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.OpenForWrite(String currentMachineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.InternalWriteEvent(UInt32 eventID, UInt16 category, EventLogEntryType type, String[] strings, Byte[] rawData, String currentMachineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type)
   ...................
 .....................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified ProcesModel's Identity of AppPool from NetworkService to LocalSystem and everything is working.

Although this is not public facing site and is a corporate distributed setup which will run within its own domain but one can still argue about security risk.

and possible solution can be

*To separate the Event writing code from Imperosnation*

or just elevate permission for offending code.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a custom event log? If so, refer to

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49dwckkz(v=vs.80).aspx

-- and in particular

> In general, create the new event source during the installation of your application. This allows time for the operating system to refresh its list of registered event sources and their configuration. If the operating system has not refreshed its list of event sources and you attempt to write an event with the new source, the write operation will fail. If creating the source during installation is not an option, then try to create the source well ahead of the first write operation, perhaps during your application initialization. ***If you choose this approach, be sure your initialization code is running with administrator rights on the computer. These rights are required for creating new event sources.***

Comment: Thanks for the response and yes it is custom event. If i install client on the same machine as of server then it is able to write the event and when client is on another machine it fails to write event remote client only write events when user from remote machine is added in administrators group of server which is pure security hack and can't deploy it to customer site.

Comment: How are you installing the client? As discussed in the MSDN article it _must_ be installed using administrative rights to create the custom log. After the application has been installed and the log has been created you can then run the application as a regular user. This is because you need to write the custom log details to the registry.

Comment: update Jeremy , its still a problem, i have created a small app which creates eventsource before even i start the service and while checking what user is passed , my service is able to write event when it is doing some operations at its own eg some initialization. but when ever a remote client hits the service and it just start going mad .so more or less it is security issue rather than event source it self.

Comment: Rep given for providing some insight though that was not issue with setup, I hope somebody else will find it useful.